# How to convert DeviceGray color to rgb?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I read pdf structure using `itext 7.0.4` library and when I read `stream` I found `DeviceGray color` in following form:

```
1 g
```

and how can I convert it to `RGB` format?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Give us a sketch of solution please!

Comment: @D.Lawrence No, I didn't try anything because I don't know how to convert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float[] hsv = color.getColorValue();
int rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsv[0], hsv[1], hsv[2]);
Color target = new Color(rgb);
```

where `color` is instance of `com.itextpdf.kernel.color.DeviceGray`